# How should I respond to this user?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, question-quality

This is the comments discussion - [Last character taken twice by textwatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465102/last-character-taken-twice-by-textwatcher#comment36563239_23465102)

Anyway, a user posted on meta spamming/complaining his question is not being answered promptly - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255629/not-geting-a-solution-for-my-question. Anyway, I wrote to him in the comments, saying "Fix my code" questions should be closed, and he says the site is saying in the FAQ that it's a place for beginner's questions.

I'm not sure if I am correct in this case, and generally, there have been other users who claim the site is there to help them. What is the best response, were my comments appropriate?

In general, when a user behaves like that, what is the appropriate response?

Comment: [It](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255629/2389078) isn't deleted.

Comment: Thanks, updated. This guy really thinks everyone here is his support team.

Comment: I had edited it myself if meta allowed, and I also don't like this kind of questions where proper debugging is not done. Although, I am not an expert, but, your last comment on that question feels like it can scare away the user from SO. I don't know if that is a 100% correct comment or not. But again, I am not expert and will follow-up to find out what was right thing to do in this case.

Comment: Scare him into doing his own debugging?

Comment: No, by scaring him away, I meant, the user might think this is not a good place to be on and might not come back.

Comment: We are not here to teach people how to debug. And we should not debug their code for them, that does not help. I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 4):

"Fix my code" questions are questions with huge code blocks saying "my code doesn't work".

This question states the problem in a single sentence and has the relevant code (24 LOC) included. Looks fine to me.

If you want to close every question that asks to fix a problem in a code snippet, we can probably close half of the questions on SO.

Comment: But doesn't he still ask us to fix his code? As opposed to asking a generic question that can be relevant to anyone's code (and thus useful to future visitors)?

Comment: @sashoalm We got rid of the *too localised* close reason a while ago ([link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns/185109)). How are you so sure it will not be useful to anyone else?

Comment: Easy - I don't insist on 100% certainty, 99.99% is fine for me. But to tell you the truth, his spam question on meta and the attitude gave set the tone of my comments more than anything else. It gave away the fact that he thinks StackOverflow is here so he can leech off it, and make others do his work.

Comment: While his attitude might give off that vibe, yours isn't the nicest either. Aren't situations like this meant to be handled by- instead of doing his "homework" for him, pointing him in the right direction without actually giving him the entire answer, even a link to where he can find information on what he is looking for? Rather than giving attitude back to a new user and pretty much telling him to get off the site and go to "rent a programmer"..